# Modify a specific element's class height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of elements where I would like to modify the CSS attributes `width` and `height` for the class of a single element.

I have this HTML with the randomly generated classes `class1`, `class2`, `class3`, etc...

```
<div class="gantt_row class1 white-grid-row"></div>
<div class="gantt_row class2 white-grid-row"></div>
<div class="gantt_row class1 white-grid-row"></div>//I want to change the css class class1 width for this element only. 
<div class="gantt_row class1 white-grid-row"></div>
```

If I have

```
.class1{width: 33px;}
```

I would like to change it to

```
.class1{width: 40px;}
```

For instance, I have the element list

```
let ganttRows = $('.white-grid-row');

let classesToKeep = ['gantt_row', 'task-parent', 'white-grid-row', 'odd'];
for (let i = 0; i < ganttRows.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ganttRows[i].classList.length; j++) {
    if (!classesToKeep.includes(ganttRows[i].classList[j])) {
      let className = ganttRows[i].classList[j];
      $("." + className).css('width', 33); //this changes the elements width, I need to change the width of class1
      //how can I modify class1 for this element only or replace the class with a copy of class1 except for the width
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify the height and width of that randomly generated class?

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. Are you trying to change the width/height for one element, or for the entire class?

Comment: I need to modify the class of that element.

Comment: We don't know what element you refer to. All we can see is it has some class pulled from `gantRows[i]` Provide a [mcve]

Comment: For starters, explain what you mean by "randomly generated class" ...? And "the specified element" - specified where/how? // Most likely it'll make the most sense if you just add a second class to that specific element, and then use `.someClass.moreSpecificForSomeReason` as selector in your CSS to apply the different formatting ...

Comment: Ok I will edit the question.

Comment: My guess is that `$(gantRows[i]).width(33)` is what you want ... hard to tell though without more detail

Comment: Your comment says `I need to modify the class of that element` but your question asks `How can I modify the height and width of that randomly generated class?` Are you trying to change the height and width, or the class name?

Comment: Do you want to change the css class attributes, not the elements class or style, right? ex.: in css file you have: **.classA{width: 30px}** then you want to change it to **.classA{width: 50px}**   is that?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Yes. But only for 1 element not the entire class. I have updated the question.

Comment: Here's how to change elements that don't have one of the `classesToKeep`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kmyLt0tx/ Still not sure if that's what you're looking for though. A `class` provides initial styling; changing an element using `.css()` will override it (because it adds the style inline, which is more powerful than the class rule)

Comment: maybe you didn't get the mean of 'class'. A class is to set css attributes to all elements that use it. If 2 elements uses this class, those 2 elements will have the same attributes. the only way to "avoid" that, is using inline css, that have superiority to css classes... so for that single element, add **theElementYouWant.style.width = '50px';** (or .css() as mentioned above)

Comment: If you change the width for `class1` it will apply the change to all elements in `class1`. You need to either apply a different class to the element in question, or change that element's height/width individually.

Comment: @freginold Thanks, that's what I'll do. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the width for `class1` it will apply the change to all elements in `class1`. You need to either apply a different class to the element in question, or change that element's height/width individually.

```
$(thisElement).css('width', 33);
```

Applying a specific class might be a better solution for you, because then you can just toggle the class anywhere in your code you want and it will change the height and/or width.